# How to convert multiple span to image

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a page which lists a series of news posts, and each post has a number of images where the URL's are placed into span's. These are then converted into images when you hover over the related post title. I've done this due to performance issues with so many images on the page.

My problem though is that when you hover over the post title each span within that particular post is then replaced with an image using only the 'first' image url. So where was: **image-1, image-2, image-3**, it then becomes: **image-1, image-1, image-1**.

Do I need to loop through the spans one by one to do this?

I have used the following javascript:

```
$('.article-post').hover(function() {
    // Find our span
    var elem = $(this).find('span.image');
    // get our img url
    var src = elem.attr('data-original');
    // Change span to img using the value from data-original
    elem.replaceWith('<img src="' + src + '"/>');
});
```

And here is my HTML layout:

```
<article class="article-post">
    <header class="article-header">
        <h1>Title...</h1>
        <div class="image-preview">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span class="image" data-original="http://www..../wp-content/uploads/2016/04/image-1.jpg" >
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span class="image" data-original="http://www..../wp-content/uploads/2016/04/image-2.jpg" >
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span class="image" data-original="http://www..../wp-content/uploads/2016/04/image-3.jpg" >
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
    ...
</article>
```

Comment: You have more than one span element, so you need to call `.each` when calling `.find` because you have an array of elements to iterate through them, and display all of them instead of only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.each()` to iterate all `span.image` elements and perform the desired operation.

```
$('.article-post').hover(function() {

    // Find all span's iterate and replace with image
    $(this).find('span.image').each(function(){
        var elem = $(this);

        // get our img url
        var src = elem.attr('data-original');

        // Change span to img using the value from data-original
        elem.replaceWith('<img src="' + src + '"/>');
    })
});
```

```js
$('.article-post').hover(function() {

  // Find all span's iterate and replace with image
  $(this).find('span.image').each(function() {
    var elem = $(this);

    // get our img url
    var src = elem.attr('data-original');

    // Change span to img using the value from data-original
    elem.replaceWith('<img src="' + src + '"/>');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="article-post">
  <header class="article-header">
    <h1>Title...</h1>
    <div class="image-preview">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <span class="image" data-original="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJ0Rx.jpg?s=32&g=1"></span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="image" data-original="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOwgU.png?s=32&g=1"></span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
</article>
```

Comment: Personal preference, but it might also be worth using `.data()` to get data attributes, rather than `.attr()`

Comment: @DBS, As `.data()` will create data in internal cache if its not there. hence not required in this scenario. However I also prefer `.data()`

Comment: Thank you @Satpal, that makes sense to me now and should help me going forward with (slowly) learning Javascript. Thanks also DBS, I'll consider that in future.